# Forcing 40MHz wireless channel width on 2011 MacBook Pro

Tags: wireless-networking, router, macbook

My router is a Netgear WNDR3700 Wireless N - 40MHz-wide channels with 300Mbps data rate.

My MacBook will only connect using 20MHz-wide channels so I'm stuck at 130Mbps.

How do I force my MacBook Pro to connect using the full 40MHz-wide channels that my router offers?

Comment: Those MBP's deliberately won't do 40 MHz on 2.4 GHz, but I'd expect they could do so on the 5 GHz bands. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to buy an 802.11n or 802.11ac Wi-Fi Access Point (wireless router) that supports the 5GHz band.

Your Netgear WNDR7000 appears to be a 2.4GHz-only device. Apple products don't support channels wider than 20MHz in the 2.4GHz band, because it takes up too much of the band and doesn't leave enough room for Bluetooth.

So you'll need to buy a Wi-Fi AP that supports the 5GHz band if you want your Mac to use 40MHz-wide channels.

Comment: i made a typo, my router is a wndr3700

Comment: @ssj So your router does support simultaneous dual band. Set it up, preferably with different network names, and you’re good to go.